# Is it possible to map filegroups in sql server 2012 to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-storage

Currently our MS SQL server 2012(on-premises) uses filestream to store files. The filestreams are stored in separate filegroups. But as the number files is increasing we are afraid it will affect the overall performance of the database. So we are planning to move these files to Azure Blob Storage. 
I found an article in MSDN about keeping data files in azure storage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466438.aspx
But believe this is for SQL Server 2014.

So, is there a similar approach for 2012?

Or am I left with uploading the file to azure from application and keeping the path in database? Uploading file from application is a very big rework and maintaining ACID properties poses a question of doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, FileStream guarantees transactional consistency between relational tables in SQL Server and BLOBs stored outside of SQL Server, in the file system.
SQL just stores references to the BLOBs to handle DML operations across them. 
This keeps their overhead small. Maintenance operations (e.g. Backup/Restore, index rebuilds, etc) apply only to relational tables (no BLOBs). 
Because of this, deployments using FileStream can scale to TBs of BLOBs without significantly impacting SQL Server performance. To increase I/O throughput add multiple files, striped across different disks, to the FileStream filegroups. 
Other recommendations at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206979(v=sql.105).aspx

SQL Server Data Files (introduced in SQL14) doesn't support FileStream/FileTable (the underlying driver doesn't recognize the Azure BLOB path). In any case, I expect doing this would impact transactional performance due to high network latency compared to local storage.